# C# open UserControl from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to get my `UserControl` that I have on the left side in my `SplitPanel` to open up a new user control in the right side. The buttons above open a `UserControl` in the left side; however, I can't get the buttons in the left side to open a new `UserControl` in the right side of the `SplitPanel`. Appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region Buttons
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Contains(left_Settings.Instance))
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(left_Settings.Instance);
            left_Settings.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            left_Settings.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            left_Settings.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
}
```

-

```
public partial class left_Settings : UserControl
{
    private static left_Settings _instance;

    public static left_Settings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new left_Settings();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public left_Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Contains(right_settings_start.Instance))
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(right_settings_start.Instance);
            right_settings_start.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            right_settings_start.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            right_settings_start.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

-

```
public partial class right_settings_start : UserControl
{
    private static right_settings_start _instance;

    public static right_settings_start Instance
    {

        get
        {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new right_settings_start();
                }

                return _instance;
        }
    }
    public right_settings_start()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code does something similar, but using panels and directly instantiating the controls rather than using an internal "instance" property.

```
Control myControl = new Control();
//Do initialization stuff
RightPanel.Controls.Add(myControl);
//Do Docking and Layout stuff
myControl.Show();
```

From what I can see the only thing you are missing is the `Control.Show()` command.  Make certain that your control actually gets loaded, this is more than just adding it and bringing it to the front, you have to tell the code to Show it.  Setting Breakpoints inside the `Control_Load` event should let you make sure that its actually showing up.

**update**

The other reason this may not work is that the SplitContainer itself exists as an object on the form, but you are trying to access it from inside the left_settings object...which can't see it.  Try referencing it as `this.ParentForm.splitContainer1` instead and see if it can find it.   You might need to make it a public object if left_settings can't see it, or provide some other accessor for it.

Comment: Hi @Nevyn thanks for the tip, however the buttonclick part where i add it to split container from my left control is giving me the error that "splitcontainer1 does not exist in this current context". Cant seem to find a solution to this part of the problem

Comment: That would make sense because you're in a completely different control.  You need to look over your scope again.  To accomplish what you are looking for, in the way you are trying to accomplish it, splitcontainer1 needs to be a public object inside the top level form, and you need to use "this.ParentForm.splitcontainer1"...or something similar...inside the control in order to locate it